# java find the smallest of two numbers coming from two different object types when one can be null

Tags: java, min

I'm trying to figure out the best way of grabbing the smallest of two numbers when the numbers are attributes inside of two different objects.  Each, but not both, of the objects can be null, which can lead to null pointer exceptions.  Each object has their own getValue() method, which will return a Long value.  There's the basic if/else that I'd prefer not to do:

```
if (obj1 != null && obj2 != null) {  // neither object is null
    minValue = obj1.getValue() <= obj2.getValue() ? obj1.getValue() : obj2.getValue();
} else if (obj1 == null && obj2 != null) { // only obj1 is null
    minValue = obj2.getValue();
} else { // only obj2 is null (they can't both be null, so we don't need an if for the situation where they're both null)
    minValue = obj1.getValue();
}
```

I've tried some other things:

```
// can throw null pointer exception
Collections.min(Arrays.asList(obj1.getValue(), obj2.getValue()));

// while both objects have a getValue() method, they are of different types, so mapping doesn't work
Collections.min(Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2)
    .filter(obj -> obj != null)
    .map(obj -> obj.getValue()) // this line will fail since the methods correspond to different objects
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I feel like this should be a fairly easy problem, but my brain's not allowing it to work.  There's due to be some min function where you can bipass a situation where the object can be null?

Comment: What are the type(s) of `value`?

Comment: They are of type Long

Comment: Why not just catch the NullPointerException?

Comment: because that's ugly :/ also, it's more standard here to check for null first than to catch the null pointer

Comment: Try to use mapToLong https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html

Comment: mapToLong is probably more appropriate than map, but that still runs into the issue that "getValue()" is a method on 2 different types of objects (they're not the same pojo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long minValue = Math.min(obj1 == null ? Long.MAX_VALUE : obj1.getValue(),
                         obj2 == null ? Long.MAX_VALUE : obj2.getValue());
```

Comment: What if `x.getValue() == null`?

Comment: Rats! Just as I was typing up the same thing!

Comment: @BoristheSpider it shouldn't, according to the OP. So that will throw an NPE and signal the precondition violation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but if I do, something like this could work:

```
if(obj1 == null) 
   minValue = obj2.getValue();
else if(obj2 == null)
   minValue = obj1.getValue();
else minValue = obj1.getValue() < obj2.getValue() ? obj1.getValue() : obj2.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method that takes in your ObjType, does a null check and returns Long.MAX_VALUE, or the value if it's null.

```
public Long getVal(ObjType val)
{
    if(val != null)
    {
       return val.getValue();
    }
    return Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

then do

```
Math.min(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: Objects arent same type